# Plot Different facecolor in the same axes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

Im kinda new to Python and Datascience.

I have a Dataset with two inputs `x1` and `x2` and one output `y`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'x1': [1, 2, 2, 1, 0.5, -1, -2, -2, -1, -0.5], 'x2': [1, 1, 2, 2, 0.5, -1, -1, -2, -2, -0.5], 'y': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})

    x1   x2  y
0  1.0  1.0  0
1  2.0  1.0  0
2  2.0  2.0  0
3  1.0  2.0  0
4  0.5  0.5  0
5 -1.0 -1.0  1
6 -2.0 -1.0  1
7 -2.0 -2.0  1
8 -1.0 -2.0  1
9 -0.5 -0.5  1
```

I've plotted this dataset :

```
plt.scatter(df.x1[df['y']==1], df.x2[df['y']==1], color='red')
plt.scatter(df.x1[df['y']==0], df.x2[df['y']==0], color='blue')
plt.show()
```

And what i want to do is to have in the same plot a different background for my classes points. So the results that i want, is something like this :

[image]

Im not really familiar with Matplotlib, the best i could achiev is to have two different axes for each class, but that's **not** what i really want to do..

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame({'x1': [1, 2, 2, 1, 0.5, -1, -2, -2, -1, -0.5], 'x2': [1, 1, 2, 2, 0.5, -1, -1, -2, -2, -0.5], 'y': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(20, 10))
ax0.scatter(df.x1[df1['y']==1], df.x2[df1['y']==1], color='red')
ax0.set_facecolor('xkcd:blue')
ax1.scatter(df.x1[df1['y']==0], df.x2[df1['y']==0], color='blue')
ax1.set_facecolor('xkcd:red')
plt.show()
```

[image: matpl]

I want this result but in the same axes, any solution please ?

Comment: An excellently formatted Q. Love how you included a sketch of your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using matlab's `fill_between` method for this:

*Note: You can create a function which could dynamically build the slope of your line of separation.*

```
# Get X Values
X = {x for x in df['x1']}
X.update({x for x in df['x2']})
X.update({min(X)-0.25, max(X)+0.25})
X = pd.Series(list(X)).sort_values()


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10, 4))

# Plot the backgrounds first to avoid overwriting the colors
ax.fill_between(X,-1*X,X.min(), color='blue', alpha=0.7)
ax.fill_between(-X,X.max(),(X), color='red', alpha=0.7)

ax.scatter(x = 'x1', y='x2', data = df[df['y']==1], color='red')
ax.scatter(x = 'x1', y='x2', data = df[df['y']==0], color='blue')
plt.show()
```